# How to call Java's Stream.collect() from groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, java-stream

Having some background with FP from Scala I really don't like Groovy's names for collections methods. Given that and some architectural choices made above, I found using a Java 8 streams API (plus java.util.Optional) in Groovy code an appealing solution.

Until I hit this:

```
def finalCollection = [ 'some', 'items', 'really', 'not', 'important' ].stream()
        .map { aMethodReturningOptional(it) } //map String to Optional<Item>
        .flatMap { it.map(Stream.&of).orElseGet(Stream.&empty) } //convert to Stream<Item>
        .collect() //Groovy's collect, not stream's!
```

Note it works only in Groovy 2+ - [treating closure as lambda](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/04/groovy-goodness-use-closures-as-java.html).
What bothers me is the last line of the example code. Groovy translates the call to the `DefaultGroovyMethods.collect()` instead of `Stream.collect()` that I originally wanted to use. Of course then the last line would be:

```
        .collect(Collectors.toList()) //Should call Java collect, but it doesn't
```

It seems counter-intuitive to me, that some extension method is called instead of native, 'built-in' method of the class.

How can I rewrite the example so the `Stream.collect()` method would be called?

**UPDATE**: After some more fiddling, I've found out what problem I had originally. I wrote `.collect{Collectors.toList()}` (note curly braces), which of course called Groovy method, not Java. Note to self: remember to quadruple-check before posting...

Comment: So, what happens if you call `collect(Collectors.toList())`, instead of `collect()`? I'm not a groovy expert, but since you call collect() without argument, why would groovy call Stream.collect(), since that method expects a Collector as argument?

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet… If you call the groovy method, it's going to use the groovy method.  Try calling the Java 8 method?

Comment: OK, after some more experimenting I've found out what problem I had. In original experiment I wrote `collect{Collectors.toList()}` (note curly braces) which is of course not what it should be. Silly me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) you can get what you want to do:

```
import java.util.stream.*

class Item {
    final String name

    Item(name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        name
    }
}

def itemize(String name) {
    Optional.of(new Item(name))
}


def finalCollection = [ 'some', 'items', 'really', 'not', 'important' ].stream()
        .map { itemize(it) } //map String to Optional<Item>
        .flatMap { it.map(Stream.&of).orElseGet(Stream.&empty) } //convert to Stream<Item>
        .collect (Collectors.toList()) 

assert 'java.util.ArrayList' == finalCollection.class.name        
assert finalCollection.collect { it.name } == ['some', 'items', 'really', 'not', 'important']
```

Anyway, with groovy 2.4.5 the above is working also with

```
def finalCollection = [ 'some', 'items', 'really', 'not', 'important' ].stream()
        .map { itemize(it) } //map String to Optional<Item>
        .flatMap { it.map(Stream.&of).orElseGet(Stream.&empty) } //convert to Stream<Item>
        .collect()
```

that uses [groovy's collect](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#collect(java.lang.Object)):

> transforming each item into a new value using Closure.IDENTITY as a
>   transformer, basically returning a list of items copied from the
>   original object.

Answer (score 2):

On my side, I found a solution to use Java Stream, Collectors in Groovy Scripts.

By casting the parameter of collect. It forces the usage of `Stream.collect()` instead of Groovy's collect()

```java
import java.util.stream.Collector
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
//...
List<String> stringsAsList = ["aa","bbb"];
return stringsAsList.stream().collect((Collector)Collectors.joining("", "", "", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy 2.5.0 and above adds [`toList`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) and [`toSet`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toSet()) methods as [enhancements to Stream](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/stream/Stream.html). No need to use  `Collectors.toList()` anymore.

```
def finalCollection = [ 'some', 'items', 'really', 'not', 'important' ].stream()
        .map { it }
        .flatMap { it.map(Stream.&of).orElseGet(Stream.&empty) }
        .toList()
```